# Gradient over text and active links

Tags: html, css, gradient

I put fixed position white-to-transparent PNG over my text on the top of window and it works fine: when I am scroling my page text smothly dissapear. The problem is: I cant click on links that are situated under my gradient. I understand WHY it happend, and I understand that my obvious solution with putting image above text isn't do for me.

Is there are another solutions to put gradient image over text and make links under this image to stay active.

Thanks.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/fl00r/sBy6G/10/

Comment: Can you provide the code in question so that we can look into the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fl00r/sBy6G/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fl00r/sBy6G/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none;` however, older browsers will not support this method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events

Other than that all I can suggest is going down the JS route and attaching click events.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `z-index` for the gradient `div` as follows: `z-index: -1;` and you will still have the same effect you want and the links under it (actually the text and the links will be above it because the second `div` `z-index` is automatically set to 0) will work.

here is a link to my changes http://jsfiddle.net/sBy6G/8/